# Implement Recursive Finding of Element (if not found) in Selenium Page Object Model

Tags: c#, selenium, pageobjects

I am implementing Selenium Page Object Pattern in my Automation Framework and the website which is going to test again is little unstable

So, basically I want to extend Selenium FindsBy Class and add specific attribute to this which allows a webelement to be tracked multiple times until it is actually found..

To explain it better :

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "li.config-btn button[class *= 'configure icon-settings']")]
private IList<IWebElement> SettingsButton;
```

On the backend, there is my custom logic handling the waitandretry attribute

What is the most proper way of doing it?

Since FindsBy Class are sealed, you can not inherit it, so how could I extend the FindsBy Functionality and implement my stuffs?

So ,basically what i need is

```
[FindsByNew(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "li.config-btn button[class *= 'configure icon-settings']", WaitRetry = 3)]
private IList<IWebElement> SettingsButton;
```

Is there anything, they are already providing which am unaware of?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I didn't understand the requirement properly, but code you posted is I think already taken care of by the CSS selector.

Comment: Do you know Page Object Pattern by Selenium?

Comment: I am aware of it, but how does that model affects this implimentation

Comment: @ShobhitMaheshwari Not a C# user but try the out-of-box RetryingElementLocator? https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_RetryingElementLocator.htm

Comment: I'm working with Selenium for more then 2 years but I wasn't aware of this RetryingElementLocator. I think it's an alternative for the FluentWait Method I gave in my answer altough I think thisRetryingElementLocator only ignores NoSuchElementException and not the other ones I added to my fluent wait method. Searching for more information about this locator I found an excellent site with more information: http://developers.perfectomobile.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21431059

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **a webelement to be tracked multiple times**? As @Frank mentioned possibly [**WebDriverWait Class**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm) in-conjunction with [**ExpectedConditions Class**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) will alone cater to your requirements.

Comment: @Frank, edited my question, may be now this makes more sense!!

Comment: But what about the RetryLocator in the constructor of the page class, what's your opinion about that? PageFactory.InitElements(this, new RetryingElementLocator(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))); It's doing the same as you try to accomplish in your 'extended FindBy', but now for all Elements in your class and in a more fluent manner.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to extend the FindsBy class and I'm not sure if it's the best solution for your problem. I'm using a fluent wait method to achieve what you are looking for. Here's an example for clicking on a webelement where four type of exceptions are ignored for a certain waittime. When the element is not found after this waittime a TimeOutException is thrown.

```
public static void WaitAndClick(this IWebDriver driver, IWebElement webelement)
{
    var fluentWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Configuration.WaitTime);
    fluentWait.Until(webDriver =>
    {
        try
        {
            webelement.Click();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is TargetInvocationException ||
                ex is NoSuchElementException ||
                ex is InvalidOperationException ||
                ex is ElementNotVisibleException)
            {
                return false; //The function will rerun.
            }
            {
                throw; //Throw exception if it's not a type to be ignored.
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is probably a very basic question, but what about returning false in the Until function causes it to retry?

Comment: @rescis yes this function will try to locate the webelement as long as one of the four exceptions occurs and the maximum wait time has not passed.

Comment: I want to extend this functionality to selenium original page object pattern , so if i pass any custom attribute to the class say [WaitAndRetry], It lets me write any custom method which actually waits and retries

Comment: Edited my question, may be now this makes more sense of what i want